# What kind of series is this? Time series Model Choice

Tags: time-series, model-selection, state-space-models

I am trying to model a series (mainly as self-education, as a way of deepening my time series knowledge). The series is percentage growth in GDP per capita for the United States, taken from the World Bank World Development Indicators databank.

I would like some advice on deciding what kind of series is represented in the graph below, and how to go about modelling it?

[image]

The data is annual, and is the percentage growth on the previous year. I do have a  preference for modelling the percentage change rather than some other transformation, like the absolute value, as this is what I am directly interested in. I have a preference for using a dynamic linear (state space) model, so I don't need to assume my series is stationary [edit: I realised that there was a false assumption in how I originally put this, as pointed out by @Richard Hardy]. I am thinking that this is perhaps a linear trend (albeit a weak one) plus something else--but what is the something else, and how might I go about assessing the reasonableness of my modelling choices? As you might expect, there seems to be a degree of cyclicity, though not a very regular one, so I understand that I wouldn't necessarily want to model a six year seasonal pattern or anything like that. Maybe a second-order (intercept plus slope) polynomial plus an auto-regressive component? if anyone had any suggestions, I would be grateful.

What I want as an output is some kind of filtered and smoothed series, so that it represents the underlying state and sees the spikiness as noise.

Comment: *so I don't need to assume my series is stationary, as in ARIMA modelling*: ARMA is usually assumed to be stationary (though you can also obtain nonstationary versions if you do not restrict the parameters to the stationary region), but ARIMA can easily be nonstationary; this is what the **I** part in AR**I**MA accounts for.

Comment: Sometimes the context will provide clues as to reasonable modelling approaches. If these were stock returns, for example, the graph suggests some reversal of extreme moves over next year or two on top of any underlying base trend.